# Can I use DirectoryModuleCatalog to load modules from application path

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I have been trying to load IModule type Modules from current application path by setting the application path in Module Path. But it throws exception. If I add the same dlls in Modules folder and then specify the same in ModulePath then it picks up easily. 
I have referred https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479(v=pandp.40).aspx
to create my Module, but there is no specific way to load from current application path. Everywhere there is a way to open from directories other than current application path. I need to know is there any specific reason that ModuleCatalog does not support loading from current application path.

Answer (score 0):

This was simple, my problem was I could load modules using Modules folder, but not application root folder.

`DirectoryModuleCatalog directoryCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };

We can do it as -

DirectoryModuleCatalog directoryCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory };